# What's a correct way for a batch file to run itself with params?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, parameters

I have a batch file. In which, I need to start another copy of itself in a new window with a parameter. I tried the command `start "" "%~0" "Param"` but it said `'"Param"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` and didn't start anything. The only way I could get it to work was `start %~0 Param` , but I figured that would crash if the path had spaces. So **What is the correct way to start another instance of the current batch file with parameters?**

Comment: Do you mean another **additional** instance, and the current stay running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start a second cmd shell, something like:

```
start "" Cmd.exe %~0 parameters
```

just to give each iteration of the batch file its own command shell.

---

*Note by OP: I had to do the following:*

```
start cmd.exe /C %~0 parameters
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, don’t know why I didn’t think of that. Thank you!!

Comment: Actually, this isn't working for me. I had to do start `cmd.exe /C %~0 parameters`

Answer (score 1):

In order to call another batch file from a batch file, use `call "name of script.bat"` or `start "name of script.bat"

Although you can do it without, unexpected results will happen, given that it will continuously call itself.

so technically, you can just write

```
%0 MyParam
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid an infinite loop, check if args are present:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SU_1298393.cmd
@Echo off
If "%~1" neq "" goto :HasArgs
Echo restart with parms
"%~0" "parms"

:HasArgs
Echo %0 started with %*
Pause
Exit /B
```

Sample run:

```
> SU_1298393.cmd
restart with parms
"SU_1298393.cmd" started with "parms"
Press any key to continue . . .

> SU_1298393.cmd foo bar
SU_1298393.cmd started with foo bar
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: It’s only in a specific case but thank you!